# How to use Automapper with Object in Object

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to Map two types of Objects but I didn't find the way to do it.

User class:

```
public partial class TUser
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("login")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Column("password")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column("role")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Role { get; set; }
        [Column("isDeleted")]
        public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
        [Column("avatarUrl")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
        [Column("iso")]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string Iso { get; set; }
        [Column("lastLogonDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? LastLogonDate { get; set; }
        [Column("createdDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [Column("lastUpdatedDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdNavigation")]
        public virtual TWorker TWorker { get; set; }
    }
```

UserForLogin Class:

```
public class UserForLogin
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string Login { get; set; }      
        public string Role { get; set; }   
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }       
        public string Iso { get; set; }      
        public TWorker TWorker { get; set; }
    }
```

TWorker class:

```
public partial class TWorker
    {
        public TWorker()
        {
            TWorkerToWorkType = new HashSet<TWorkerToWorkType>();
            TrEventToWorker = new HashSet<TrEventToWorker>();
            TrWorkerToWorkerCategory = new HashSet<TrWorkerToWorkerCategory>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("lastname")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        [Column("firstname")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("phone")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Column("address")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Column("postcode")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [Column("locality")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        [Column("workerCategoryKey")]
        public int? WorkerCategoryKey { get; set; }
        [Column("sexe")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Sexe { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(TUser.TWorker))]
        public virtual TUser IdNavigation { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("WorkerKeyNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<TWorkerToWorkType> TWorkerToWorkType { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("WorkerKeyNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<TrEventToWorker> TrEventToWorker { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("WorkerKeyNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<TrWorkerToWorkerCategory> TrWorkerToWorkerCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapperProfiles class:

```
 public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<TUser, UserForLogin>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.TWorker,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker)
                );                         
        }
```

But TWorker is always null and I can't find what am I doing wrong?
If I use TUser only to return my object without Automapper code, TWorker contains the values I want.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are triggering the mapping?

Comment: Why do you have this `ForMember()` line in there? The `TWorker` entity exists in both classes and the type matches. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Nested-mappings.html

Answer (score 2):

You just need to implement the map for the subObject and autoMapper will handle it for you.
To be precise, if you map a property to another property which has a different type, autoMapper will try to find a corresponding map.